# Get Text variable from Custom Name with mobs (Minecraft)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a mob(sheep) with custom name is "ABC" here:[image: Sheep]

I have tried this command : `data get entity <sheep> CustomName`
[image]

But i want to it return `ABC` only, not `{"text":"ABC"}`. I also tried something like `data get entity <sheep> CustomName.text` but it didn't work. Thanks for any helps!